# Is it possible to make Android Room tables case insensitive?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, schema, android-room, case-insensitive

I created a database on my local computer, to prepopulate it into Room. The Database is locally in MySQL on a Windows computer. However I used the SQL Statements from Room to create it and only made some minor changes necessary due to the different dialects. The scheme therefore is the same as it is supposed to. However the problem is, that when I convert it into SQLite, the converter does not care about upper and lower case and writes all table names in lower case. (Since the MySQL-Database is case-insensitive with table names.) Which results in an invalid database scheme in Android, just because the table name in the foreign key is written in lowercase, and does not start with an uppercase letter.
This is the error-message without formatting (since it shows very obvious, that there is not actually a difference):

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema: Strengths(bi.deutsch_kirundi_app.db.entities.germanSpecificTables.Strengths).
     Expected:
    TableInfo{name='Strengths', columns={name=Column{name='name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, singularStrength=Column{name='singularStrength', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, pluralStrength=Column{name='pluralStrength', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='Strengths', onDelete='NO ACTION', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[singularStrength], referenceColumnNames=[id]}, ForeignKey{referenceTable='Strengths', onDelete='NO ACTION', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[pluralStrength], referenceColumnNames=[id]}], indices=[Index{name='index_Strengths_singularStrength', unique=false, columns=[singularStrength]}, Index{name='index_Strengths_pluralStrength', unique=false, columns=[pluralStrength]}]}
     Found:
    TableInfo{name='Strengths', columns={name=Column{name='name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, singularStrength=Column{name='singularStrength', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, pluralStrength=Column{name='pluralStrength', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='strengths', onDelete='NO ACTION', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[pluralStrength], referenceColumnNames=[id]}, ForeignKey{referenceTable='strengths', onDelete='NO ACTION', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[singularStrength], referenceColumnNames=[id]}], indices=[Index{name='index_Strengths_singularStrength', unique=false, columns=[singularStrength]}, Index{name='index_Strengths_pluralStrength', unique=false, columns=[pluralStrength]}]}
```

And here is the formatted version:

```
Expected:
TableInfo{
name='Strengths', 
columns={
name=Column{name='name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, 
singularStrength=Column{name='singularStrength', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, 
defaultValue='null'}, 
id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, 
pluralStrength=Column{name='pluralStrength', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, 
defaultValue='null'}}, 
foreignKeys=[
ForeignKey{referenceTable='Strengths', onDelete='NO ACTION', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[singularStrength], 
referenceColumnNames=[id]}, 
ForeignKey{referenceTable='Strengths', onDelete='NO ACTION', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[pluralStrength], 
referenceColumnNames=[id]}], 
indices=[
Index{name='index_Strengths_singularStrength', unique=false, columns=[singularStrength]}, 
Index{name='index_Strengths_pluralStrength', unique=false, columns=[pluralStrength]}]}

Found:
TableInfo{
name='Strengths', 
columns={
name=Column{name='name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, 
singularStrength=Column{name='singularStrength', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, 
defaultValue='null'}, 
id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, 
pluralStrength=Column{name='pluralStrength', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, 
defaultValue='null'}}, 
foreignKeys=[
ForeignKey{referenceTable='strengths', onDelete='NO ACTION', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[pluralStrength], 
referenceColumnNames=[id]}, 
ForeignKey{referenceTable='strengths', onDelete='NO ACTION', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[singularStrength], 
referenceColumnNames=[id]}], 
indices=[
Index{name='index_Strengths_singularStrength', unique=false, columns=[singularStrength]}, 
Index{name='index_Strengths_pluralStrength', unique=false, columns=[pluralStrength]}]}
```

Obviously, even if I wanted to, I could not change the Foreign Keys Reference (since then it detects that the database was manipulated).
So my question is, if there is any possibility to tell Room, to just ignore casing in foreign keys` table names. (Since it also ignores it in create table statements)
Some might suggest the problem is the switched order of the foreign keys, however order doesn´t matter. Already checked that with another table, where columns were written in a switched order and it worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is, if there is any possibility to tell Room, to just ignore casing in foreign keys.

I don't believe that you can, as it's inherent with how room builds the comparisons (Expected and Found).

You say *Since the MySQL-Database is case-insensitive with table names.* so is SQLite, it's Room that is not accepting the difference at run time.

I'd suggest that this may be considered a bug, I see that you appear to have raised it as a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195242923).

Comment: Yes, I raised it as a bug, since I considered it faulty behaviour too.  Hope they´ll fix it. For now I´ll just have to go with making all my referenced entities lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

So as MikeT suggested, I reported it to Google as a bug. For the time being their is a neat, but simple work-around:
Just make all entity-classes referenced in a foreign key all-lowercase.
Like this:

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(entity = strengths::class, parentColumns = ["id"],
        childColumns = ["singularStrength"]), ForeignKey(entity = strengths::class, parentColumns = ["id"],
childColumns = ["pluralStrength"])],
indices = [Index(value=["singularStrength"]), Index(value=["pluralStrength"])])
data class strengths(@PrimaryKey val id : Int, val singularStrength : Int, val pluralStrength : Int,
                     val name : String)
```

Not so nice, because it violates naming conventions, but fairly easy to do.